# Prove that this matrix is idempotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to show that $\overline{\mathbf{J}}=\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{J}=\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^{\prime}$ is idempotent, being $\mathbf{1}$ a unit vector of $n \times 1$

By opperating, I've got that $\overline{\mathbf{J}}=\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{J}=\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^{\prime}=\frac{1}{n^2}{\mathbf{J}}$ and I don't know that's next or how to argue.

Comment: \begin{align}
   \left( \dfrac 1n \mathbf 1 \mathbf 1'\right) \cdot 
   \left( \dfrac 1n \mathbf 1 \mathbf 1'\right)
   &= \dfrac{1}{n^2} \mathbf 1 (\mathbf 1' \mathbf 1) \mathbf 1' \\
   &= \dfrac{1}{n^2} \mathbf 1 (n) \mathbf 1' \\
   &= \dfrac{1}{n} \mathbf 1 \mathbf 1' \\
\end{align}

Comment: thanks, that didn't cross my head